# rqt can not connect to Xming via SSH X11 forwarding

Tags: x11, ros, xinput, rqt

I'm running ROS 1 Noetic on Ubuntu 20, using PuTTY to forward X11 to Xming on Windows 10. RViz and Gazebo work fine, but when I run rqt, I get an error:

```
X server does not support XInput 2
failed to get the current screen resources
The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
```

Any explanation or solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to make RQT and other applications work with Xming, but found GWSL server: https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/gwsl/9NL6KD1H33V3
It works like a charm and also has few nice to have features.